# pandas dataframe list partial string matching python

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`:

df:

```
        chr          gene_name
0        1           ARF3
1        1           ABC
2        1           ARF3, ENSG123
3        1           ENSG,ARF3
4        1           ANG
5        2           XVY
6        2           PQR
7        3           RST
8        4           TAC
```

and a gene_list

```
gene_list = ['ARF3','ABC' ]
```

Now, I need to get the rows from the data frame (`df`) for which the gene name is either an exact match with elements in `gene_list`.

So, I tried:

```
df2 = df1[df.gene_name.isin(gene_list)]
```

I retrieved:

```
       chr           gene_name
0        1           ARF3
1        1           ABC
```

but what I am expecting is:

```
        chr          gene_name
0        1           ARF3
1        1           ABC
2        1           ARF3, ENSG123
3        1           ENSG,ARF3
```

so basically all the rows in the data frame where the element in `gene_list` is a substring of `gene_name` in the data frame.

I thought of using `.contains()` had it been I was looking the other way that is `gene_name` in the data frame would have been a substring on element in `gene_list`.

All the help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `join` all values with `|` (`or`):

```
gene_list = ['ARF3','ABC' ]

print ('|'.join(gene_list))
ARF3|ABC

print (df.gene_name.str.contains('|'.join(gene_list)))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
Name: gene_name, dtype: bool

df2 = df[df.gene_name.str.contains('|'.join(gene_list))]
print (df2)
   chr     gene_name
0    1          ARF3
1    1           ABC
2    1  ARF3,ENSG123
3    1     ENSG,ARF3
```

Comment: Hmmm, this solution work nice, if you need only filter values. How does it work?

Comment: This solution is wrong? Can I delete it?